# ImportError: No module named _psycopg

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I've looked at every post concerning this issue. I've (re)installed PostgreSQL on my Mac using Homebrew. I've adjusted the PATH variables. I've installed/uninstalled/reinstalled psycopg2. I've watched videos. Still, I cannot figure out how **psyco**pg2 can be squarely on my machine and yet unavailable to my database and, by extension, my Flask application. Here is my latest error message with confirmation that, yes, it's there and, no, I can't use it (or Python won't acknowledge it). Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is day two of this nonsense.

```
RCD@Ryans-MacBook-Pro ~ -  $ sudo pip3 install psycopg2
Password:

Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.7.5)

RCD@Ryans-MacBook-Pro ~ -  $ python

>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: No module named _psycopg
```

Comment: Are you sure `pip3` uses the same `python`? Can we see results of `sudo pip3 --version`, `python --version` and `which python`?

Comment: @phd pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7),      Python 2.7.14,  
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python.  Those are in the order you asked for.

Comment: Also, I ripped everything out, created a virtualenv (based on python3.7), and am now on to a new, obscure error. But, if the above output is problematic, let me know and, if possible, let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

So you've installed `psycopg2` into Python 3.7 but tried to use it in Python 2.7.

`python` and `pip` must be synchronized; the simplest way to do that is to run `python -m pip` instead of `pip`, that way you guarantee that you use correct `pip` for your current `python`.

Please remember that `sudo` uses a different `$PATH` so you'd better set the full path to your `python`:

```
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python -m pip install -U psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: I have a variety of packages to install. Some use Python3x others 2x. It's all supposed to come in from requirements.txt via 'pip3 install -r requirements.txt'. How does this affect your recommendation -- especially that last part?

Comment: How do you suppose to use both Python 2 and Python 3 with one program? It's simply impossible. You have to choose one version and install all packages for it. Of course you can have 2 different virtual environments, one for Python 2 and the other for Python 3.

Comment: Someone else with pretty much the same setup is installing this the same way with zero hangups: Flask, Flask-Session, psycopg2, SQLAlchemy, passlib.